# tax_query to get posts with a field with empty value?

Tags: metadata, wordpress

I defined a custom field, to be able to hide posts from home, like this:

```
/* Campo adicional que puede ocultar noticia de la home */
function mnd_get_custom_field( $value ) {
    global $post;
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( !empty( $custom_field ) )
        return is_array( $custom_field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $custom_field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $custom_field ) );
    return false;
}
function mnd_add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'home-page', __( 'Home page', 'mnd' ), 'mnd_meta_box_output', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mnd_add_custom_meta_box' );
function mnd_meta_box_output( $post ) {
     wp_nonce_field( 'my_mnd_meta_box_nonce', 'mnd_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>
    <p>
     <label for="mnd_hide_homepage"><?php _e( 'Hide from homepage', 'mnd' ); ?>:</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="mnd_hide_homepage" id="mnd_hide_homepage" checked="<?php echo mnd_get_custom_field( 'mnd_hide_homepage' ) == 1 ? 'checked' : ''; ?>" value="1" size="50" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
function mnd_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
     if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
     if( !isset( $_POST['mnd_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mnd_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_mnd_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
     if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', get_the_id() ) ) return;
     if( isset( $_POST['mnd_hide_homepage'] ) )
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mnd_hide_homepage', esc_attr( $_POST['mnd_hide_homepage'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'mnd_meta_box_save' );
```

and I'm trying like:

```
// The Query
$ppp = 12;
$page = $_GET['page'];
$args_count = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => false,
    'status' => 'publish'
);
$posts_home_count = new WP_Query( $args_count );
$manyPosts = $posts_home_count->found_posts;
$paginas = $manyPosts / $ppp;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
$meta_params  = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'mnd_hide_homepage',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '!=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )
);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'paged' => $page,
    'page' => $page,
    'status' => 'publish'/*,
    'meta_query' => $meta_params    */
);
//print_r ( $args );
$posts_home = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And it won't return any posts,

But if I change to

```
'compare' => '=',
```

Then it returns all the checked posts

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`?

Comment: Yes, I just Did, It won't return fields that had the value changed, whatever it's value is..

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with Meta Query sometimes and the problem is not always visible. Try the following:

1. `var_dump` the `WP_Query` object and check the SQL manually. Do you see the problem?
2. Did you try to remove `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`?
3. The “hack” solution (untested):

```php
global $wpdb;
    
$ids = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.id FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status=publish
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->post_meta
    ON $wpdb->post_meta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id
    AND $wpdb->post_meta.key = 'mnd_hide_homepage'
    AND $wpdb->post_meta.value != '1'
");

// put the ids with post__in into the WP_Query arguments
```

Maybe this is the solution. If not, it may help to find it.

Comment: Actually, my solution was making an OR query with the set value (I changed it to `yes` ) OR not exitst, but your answer is very much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array(
    'key' => 'mnd_hide_homepage',
    'value' => '1',
    'compare' => '!=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
)
```

Or

```
array(
    'key' => 'mnd_hide_homepage',
    'value' => array('1'),
    'compare' => 'NOT IN'
)
```

Comment: Your first option, it's the one I included in the question... and the second one, the seconds seems to be ignored..

Comment: In my first option i added value => '1'